# The size of a struct

Tags: c, pointers, size

Assume there is a struct `fakes`:

```
struct fakes {
....
};
```

And there is a pointer:

```
struct fakes *fakes;
```

I'm wondering whether `sizeof(struct fakes)` and `sizeof(*fakes)` are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm wondering whether `sizeof(struct fakes)` and `sizeof(*fakes)` are the same.

Yes, they are guaranteed to be the same.

Comment: They are the same indeed, but it is rather confusing to use the same identifier for a `struct` tag and an actual object.

Comment: Yes, it can be confusing to use the same identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. These are the same.

[`sizeof`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof#Use) is used to determine the amount of space a datatype occupies in memory. The compiler is really only concerned with the type, and not a particular instance of it (because all instances should take up the same amount of space). So `sizeof(struct fakes)` is guaranteed to be the same as`sizeof(*fakes)`.

Comment: Can you please explain why the following doesn't work ?

    `int a[10]={1,2,34};
    int *ptr=a;
    printf("size of aray is %d\n",sizeof(a));
    printf("size of ptr is %d\n",sizeof(*ptr));`

It gives output as 

     `size of aray is 40
     size of ptr is 4`

Comment: @Karthick No, that works. When you use `sizeof` on an array, it gives you how many bytes the array takes up. So, `sizeof` on an array of 10 `int`s where an `int` is 4 bytes yields `40`. The size of a single element `sizeof(*ptr)` or `sizeof(int)` is `4`.

Answer (score 0):

When the sizeof operator is applied to a class, struct, or union type, the result is the number of bytes in an object of that type, plus any padding added to align members on word boundaries. The result does not necessarily correspond to the size calculated by adding the storage requirements of the individual members.

When the sizeof operator is applied to a reference, the result is the same as if sizeof had been applied to the object itself.

check this out,

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4s7x1k91.aspx

Comment: Since this is C, "class" doesn't really apply. Also, although Microsoft's implementation of `sizeof` is probably standard-conforming, the linked page is really only guaranteed to apply to Visual C++, and not other implementations.